# Varnish 4 woocommerce mini cart not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, varnish, varnish-vcl

i am using the following varnish 4 configuration and althrough POST requests are not cached, when adding to cart, mini cart is not working. This is the official documentation

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-caching-plugins/

Varnish configuration is shown bellow. Any suggestions? All other caching on the server is turned off.

```
#
# This is an example VCL file for Varnish.
#
# It does not do anything by default, delegating control to the
# builtin VCL. The builtin VCL is called when there is no explicit
# return statement.
#
# See the VCL chapters in the Users Guide at https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/
# and https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExamples for more examples.

# Marker to tell the VCL compiler that this VCL has been adapted to the
# new 4.0 format.
vcl 4.0;
import std;

include "/etc/varnish/letsencrypt.vcl";

# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "9000";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
    .max_connections = 800;
}

# Only allow purging from specific IPs
acl purge {
    "localhost";
    "127.0.0.1";
}

# This function is used when a request is send by a HTTP client (Browser) 
sub vcl_recv {
    # if (std.port(server.ip) != 443) {
    #     set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
    #     return(synth(301));
    # }
    # Normalize the header, remove the port (in case you're testing this on various TCP ports)
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    # WooCommerce: The code below makes sure the AJAX "add to cart" function works 
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "add-to-cart=\d+_\d+&", "");

    set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

    # Allow purging from ACL
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        # If not allowed then a error 405 is returned
        if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
            return(synth(405, "This IP is not allowed to send PURGE requests."));
        }
        # If allowed, do a cache_lookup -> vlc_hit() or vlc_miss()
        return (purge);
    }

    # Post requests will not be cached
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.method == "POST") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # --- Wordpress specific configuration
    
    # Did not cache the RSS feed
    if (req.url ~ "/feed") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Blitz hack
    if (req.url ~ "/mu-.*") {
        return (pass);
    }

    
    # Did not cache the admin and login pages
    if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
        return (pass);
    }
    
     # Do not cache the WooCommerce pages
     ### REMOVE IT IF YOU DO NOT USE WOOCOMMERCE ###
    if (req.url ~ "/(cart|my-account|wc-api|checkout|addons|/?add-to-cart=)") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Remove the "has_js" cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "has_js=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the Quant Capital cookies (added by some plugin, all __qca)
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__qc.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp-settings-time-1 cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wp-settings-time-1=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Remove the wp test cookie
    set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "wordpress_test_cookie=[^;]+(; )?", "");

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^ *$") {
            unset req.http.cookie;
    }
    
    # Cache the following files extensions 
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g|swf|ico)") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # Normalize Accept-Encoding header and compression
    # https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/vary.html
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        # Do no compress compressed files...
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
                unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
                set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
                set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Check the cookies for wordpress-specific items
    if (req.http.Cookie ~ "wordpress_" || req.http.Cookie ~ "comment_") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if (!req.http.cookie) {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
    
    # --- End of Wordpress specific configuration

    # Did not cache HTTP authentication and HTTP Cookie
    if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
        # Not cacheable by default
        return (pass);
    }

    # Cache all others requests
    return (hash);
}

# sub vcl_synth {
#     if (resp.status == 301) {
#         set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
#         set resp.status = 301;
#         return (deliver);
#     }
# }

sub vcl_pipe {
    # Implementing websocket support (https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/users-guide/vcl-example-websockets.html)
    if (req.http.upgrade) {
        set bereq.http.upgrade = req.http.upgrade;
    }

    return (pipe);
}

sub vcl_pass {
    return (fetch);
}

# The data on which the hashing will take place
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.url);
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # # If the client supports compression, keep that in a different cache
    # if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
    #     hash_data(req.http.Accept-Encoding);
    # }

    # hash cookies for requests that have them
    if (req.http.Cookie) {
        hash_data(req.http.Cookie);
    }
     
    return (lookup);
}


# This function is used when a request is sent by our backend (Nginx server)
sub vcl_backend_response {

    # Remove some headers we never want to see
    unset beresp.http.Server;
    unset beresp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Enable cache for all static files
    # The same argument as the static caches from above: monitor your cache size, if you get data nuked out of it, consider giving up the static file cache.
    # Before you blindly enable this, have a read here: https://ma.ttias.be/stop-caching-static-files/
    if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|otf|ogg|ogm|opus|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

    # Large static files are delivered directly to the end-user without
    # waiting for Varnish to fully read the file first.
    # Varnish 4 fully supports Streaming, so use streaming here to avoid locking.
    if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bz2|flac|flv|gz|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ogm|opus|rar|tar|tgz|tbz|txz|wav|webm|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.do_stream = true;  # Check memory usage it'll grow in fetch_chunksize blocks (128k by default) if the backend doesn't send a Content-Length header, so only enable it for big objects
    }

    # Only allow cookies to be set if we're in admin area
    if (beresp.http.Set-Cookie && bereq.url !~ "^/wp-(login|admin)" && bereq.url !~ "((wp/)?wp-(login|admin)|login)") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    }

    # don't cache response to posted requests or those with basic auth
    if ( bereq.method == "POST" || bereq.http.Authorization ) {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        return (deliver);
    }
 
        # don't cache search results
    if ( bereq.url ~ "\?s=" ){
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        return (deliver);
    }
    
    # only cache status ok
    if ( beresp.status != 200 ) {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # A TTL of 24h
    set beresp.ttl = 24h;
    # Define the default grace period to serve cached content
    set beresp.grace = 30s;
    
    return (deliver);
}

# The routine when we deliver the HTTP request to the user
# Last chance to modify headers that are sent to the client
sub vcl_deliver {

    # Called before a cached object is delivered to the client.
    if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }

    # Please note that obj.hits behaviour changed in 4.0, now it counts per objecthead, not per object
    # and obj.hits may not be reset in some cases where bans are in use. See bug 1492 for details.
    # So take hits with a grain of salt
    set resp.http.X-Cache-Hits = obj.hits;

    # Remove some headers: PHP version
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;

    # Remove some headers: Apache version & OS
    unset resp.http.Server;

    # Remove some heanders: Varnish
    unset resp.http.Via;
    #Proxy cache wordpress plugin use that header
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_purge {
  # Only handle actual PURGE HTTP methods, everything else is discarded
  if (req.method == "PURGE") {
    # restart request
    set req.http.X-Purge = "Yes";
    return (restart);
  }
}

sub vcl_init {
    return (ok);
}

sub vcl_fini {
    return (ok);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved. Need to add on backend response:

```
if (!(req.url ~ "(wp-login|wp-admin|cart|my-account|checkout|addons)")) {
                unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Varnish 4 and Varnish 5 are End-Of-Life. Varnish 6 is the way to go these days. Keep in mind that there have been a couple security vulnerabilities that have only been patched in more recent versions of Varnish.

For more information about using WordPress & WooCommerce on Varnish 5 see https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/configuring-varnish-wordpress/